# Differences in how to infiltrate a layout in an Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

I have just began to use Fragments in Android and ViewBinding and I have a question. Basically I figured out that there are (at least) 2 ways how to infiltrate a layout in the onCreateView() method of a Fragment. Here are the two options:

Option 1 (this is the default one of Android Studio when creating a Fragment):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
}
```

Option 2 (with ViewBinding):

```
  private FragmentMenuBinding binding;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

I would like to know, whether there are substantial differnces between the two approaches. Are there any circumstances where you would prefer one of them over the other? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference boils down to the usage of `ViewBinding` or not in this case. In the second snippet you have the binding class with view objects ready for you to use. In the first you will have to run `findViewById` manually before accessing the view itself

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt for your answer. So is it more advicalbe to use the ViewBinding approach? I read quite often than one should rather use ViewBinding instead of findViewById()?

Comment: ViewBinding is being done at compile time through code generation. Might be slightly less error prone than your cast at runtime. Definitely less verbose. Apart from that I don't see any particular advantages, but I haven't used it so far

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and help Blackbelt. I will then stick to the ViewBinding.

Comment: yaw. enjoy it then